# Error when attempting to sign Android app: Certificate chain not found

Tags: android

I've done this before but I am running into errors this time and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have the keystore file and the unsigned apk inside the jdk bin folder where the jarsigner exe is. Here are two screenshots of my errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you entering correct password?

Comment: yes the password is correct